# Products of the reaction between cyclohexanone and N-bromosuccinimide

Tags: organic-chemistry, nucleophilic-substitution, rearrangements

#### Problem

> Treating cyclohexanone with *N*-bromosuccinimide in the presence of carbon tetrachloride gives **A**. A on treatment with aqueous KOH gives **B**. Deduce the structures of **A** and **B**.

#### Solution

> **A** is 2-bromocyclohexanone and **B** is potassium cyclopentane carboxylate.

#### Questions

1. In the first step, why did the bromine atom get attached to the second position? The carbonyl group, being electron withdrawing, should direct the incoming electrophile away from it.
2. In the second step, I am quite sure that the product mentioned is a result of Favorskii rearrangement. But there is also a possibility for the hydroxide ion to substitute bromine. Is this possible? If yes, why is the substituted product not a major product? If not, why?

Comment: With regard to your first question - consider the role of keto/enol tautomerism. There is an error in the stated answer; B is not cyclohexane carboxylate potassium salt.

Comment: Count the number of carbons!

Comment: @Waylander Could you elaborate your first statement?

Comment: It isn't the ketone that brominates, its the enol. Google is your friend! Search "enol bromination"

Comment: That explains the first part. Thank you!

Comment: I don't have a definitive answer for 2 but it is like a E2 vs SN2 for secondary haloalkanes. The solvent, temperature, and concentration will favour one or the other. See the last link below. However, it is also important to note that the hydrogen is rather acidic so it will likely favour deprotonation rather than substitution.                              https://chem.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Organic_Chemistry/Supplemental_Modules_(Organic_Chemistry)/Alkyl_Halides/Reactivity_of_Alkyl_Halides/The_Reaction_of_Alkyl_Halides_with_Hydroxide_Ions.

Comment: Also consider the steric factors; bromine is a large atom and the hydroxide ion must attack from the reverse face

Comment: thank you lots! That's convincing enough.